# Visual Studio Code Debugger not working under other connection

Tags: visual-studio-code, navision, dynamics-nav, dynamics-business-central

when I run the debugger mode under network of my home, the debugger work correctly.
But, when I try to debug from at network of my office work, it doesn't work..

It start and I can see the the dialog of the debug at top to right, but not attached.. the screen remain with blue frame.

My launch .json is very simple..

```
 {
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Microsoft cloud sandbox",
            "type": "al",
            "request": "launch",
            "startupObjectId": 2500,
            "startupObjectType": "Page",
            "breakOnError": true,     
            "breakOnRecordWrite": true,
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an network issue if it works at home.

- Check the IP-Subnet and Port of your BC MS Cloud Sandbox environment
  if possible and see if you can ping it via telnet, to see if the
  connection works.
- Also have a look in your **event viewer** (sometimes it gives you
  insights about issues you are not aware of)
- Turn off your **firewall** temporarly
- Also **VPNs and Proxys** are pretty common these days for companies. 
  Check if these might interrupt anything, might as well ask your admin
  for that.

Hope this helps out